# Android working with Google Spreadsheet

Tags: android, spreadsheet

I wonder if I can programmatically retrieve data from a Google spreadsheet, in Android, and also insert new rows into it. I am planning to do this using a HttpGet object..

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Google Docs spreadsheets API](http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/data/3.0/developers_guide.html). There's a code example for [inserting a new row](http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/data/3.0/developers_guide.html#CreatingListRows).

Comment: Is there a way to authenticate to the spreadsheet using the phone's profiles (so that the user doesn't have to type their password)?

Comment: Nels Beckman: I just typed once the username and password in the code activity, and used it whenever its necessary. however i think its possible to do as you say, but no need to make it more complicated